# take certain value from 2 different columns in a table

Tags: mysql

I have a select statement which gets the sum of interest payment as interest total. Here is the sql code I am using.

```
select  sum(round(a.Amount * e.average_rate / f.average_rate, 2)) as earningTotal ,
        sum(d.interest_payment) as interestTotal,
        sum(d.interest_paid) as NetInterest,
a.*, c.symbol, c.Abbreviation, d.*
from   investment a
inner join money_offer b
on a.ORIG_ID = b.investment_orig_id and b.UPDATE_DT is null
inner   join payment_plan d 
on d.offer_orig_id = b.ORIG_ID and d.UPDATE_DT is null
inner   join currency c 
    on  d.currency = c.ID 
inner join exchange_rates e 
    on  e.currency_id = a.Currency
inner join exchange_rates f 
    on  f.currency_id = a.Currency
where   a.Owner = 518  and
        a.UPDATE_DT is null;
```

Here is a picture which shows the table information.
[image]

The problem is that now I am only taking interest_payment and summing it up, but if there is a value > 0 in interest_paid( now its zero) for the first interest_payment which is now 0.08 then I should select the interest_paid of the first row and add it with the interest_payment of 2nd row ( 0.16 ) + and 3rd row  0.08 . There maybe be more row in the future.

So in simple terms now since all 3 rows of interest_paid is 0 so its fine, but if maybe the first row or the second row of interest paid has a value more than 0, I need to take those value and add it with the 3rd row value of interest_payment. I was thinking of making a UNION but I am not sure how to do it.